# Relationships field limited, but it should search through all entries

Tags: control-panel, relationships, fieldtype

It seems I have found something missing in the features of the relationships field. We have many native one to many relationships fields. I have to limit the results that are to be displayed on the publish page, because otherwise it will load tens of thousands of entries on opening the publish page.

However, when I search for a specific entry it will only search through the entries that are displayed by limit, say the 100 last entries of 20000 ... ?

Am I missing something? Did anyone else run into this? Should I fix some kind of custom solution to make it work properly? Switching to Playa is not an option anymore because many relationships have been made by now.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you on an ee version before 2.7.2?

Comment: Actually, I'm on version 2.7.2 :)

Comment: @Romans-8---31-39 Are you saying later versions support what I'm after?

Comment: Check out this just added bug: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20287